# visual studio online custom work items / workflow

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Visual Studio Online and trying to create custom work item types and custom workflow.  I can't seem to find any documentation or anywhere in the UI that allows you to defined these items. Anyone know how this can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As of January 2016:**
Process Customisation is supported in VSTS, details can be found in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/vsts-process-customization-futures-january-2016/).

---

**Before January 2016:**

<strike>It can't be done at the moment, however, there are [internal Microsoft teams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/09/23/visual-studio-online-update-sept-23th.aspx#10560037) using customised process templates on Visual Studio Online.</strike>

Expect this to change later this year (2015) - keep an eye on Brian Harry's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/).

The best you can get at the moment is using [Tags](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/2013-jan-30-vso) and [customise the Kanban boards](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/2013-mar-4-vso).

If you really want this feature, vote on the [Visual Studio User Voice request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online) for it.

Comment: That's right Dave!  It's on the backlog.  There is a UserVoice item for this request available here:  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online

Comment: Cheers Ed, I've edited the uservoice into the answer.

Comment: Latest from Microsoft (as of Novemmber 12, 2014): "We are investigating how we can enable customizations of the work items on the service, as well as using your own process templates." (via the link mentioned by DaveShaw). One can only hope it will make it...

Comment: I voted on this since it was in preview, and started a forum discussion around it. It was "on the roadmap" and "coming soon" back then. And that's well over 2 years ago. We adjusted our process, but it's never felt quite right. One can hope they'll commit to it soon, but don't get your hopes up...

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/vsts-process-customization-futures-january-2016/